# Hyperledger Fabric CouchDB index not found

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, couchdb, hyperledger-chaincode, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-java

I am getting a Hyperledger Fabric CouchDB index not found error...

```
2023-09-17 23:48:58.084 UTC [chaincode] HandleTransaction -> ERRO 051 [ce5a14fc] Failed to handle GET_QUERY_RESULT. error: error handling CouchDB request. Error:no_usable_index,  Status Code:400,  Reason:No index exists for this sort, try indexing by the sort fields.
```

I am using Java chaincode:

```
QueryResultsIterator<KeyValue> results = stub
        .getQueryResult("{\"selector\":{\"$not\":{\"createdDate\":null}},\"sort\":[{\"createdDate\":\"desc\"}],\"use_index\":\"createdDateIndexDoc\"}");
```

The query is to return all entries sorted by createdDate in reverse order. That is why I add the selector with not null. (BTW, the selector is mandatory... can I ignore it some how?)

The Index file I have in META-INF/statedb/couchdb/indexCreatedDateDesc.json is

```
{
    "index": {
        "fields": [{"createdDate": "desc"}]
    },
    "name" : "createdDateIndex",
    "ddoc" : "createdDateIndexDoc",
    "type" : "json"
}
```

(Note: I am looking in peer logs, couchdb logs and docker running the chaincode logs but I don't see any confirmation that the index has been installed in the CouchDB database. In which log exactly i should look for that entry to make sure the index is deployed?)

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it should be in the CouchDB logs.

I typically use the Fauxton UI. (couchdb-url:port/_utils)

The path should be META-INF/statedb/couchdb/**indexes**

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/couchdb_tutorial.html#cdb-add-index

A selector statement is required to query. An index is required for sort in a query.

https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/database/find.html#sort-syntax

Comment: Thanks. The path was definitely wrong as you pointed out. I have fixed it but I still can't find any logs in couchdb pod regarding the index when I re-deploy the chaincode. Should chaincode redeployment trigger the index generation or I need to do any specific action on that aspect? BTW, is there a selector to directly return all entries? (I am using a "not null" as a workaround as I have not found how to "select all") Thanks so much.

Comment: Also, the only logs I have in my couchdb pod are of type: [notice] 2023-09-18T14:12:16.296127Z nonode@nohost <0.31069.16> 87f6b1295f localhost:5984 127.0.0.1 iprd-user GET /iprd_iprd-chaincode/_index 200 ok 2 (nothing about the created index even after re-deploying the chaincode with the correct file path for the index)

Comment: I see index updates under info (seems to be true for install or update) in couchdb logs.

Comment: I see index updates under info (seems to be true for install or update) in couchdb logs.    [info] 2023-08-07T17:38:20.641221Z nonode@nohost <0.1122.133> -------- Index update finished for db: shards/00000000-7fffffff.....     I see several POST statements in couchdb logs for indices. Seems to correspond to the number f indices I have. But no index name shown.  [notice] 2023-08-08T15:38:24.192548Z nonode@nohost <0.8624.0> cc71be7afe couchdb0:5984 172.21.0.8 admin POST /channelName_chaincodeName/_index 200 ok 179

Comment: I see index installation attempts in peer logs      2023-08-08 15:30:37.016 UTC [lifecycle] InstallChaincode -> INFO 027 Successfully installed chaincode with package ID.......              2023-08-08 15:38:24.253 UTC [statecouchdb] ProcessIndexesForChaincodeDeploy -> INFO 076 successfully submitted index creation request present in the file [META-INF/statedb/couchdb/indexes/.........       I think chaincode update will only install any changes. So since your index is in a new location, I would assume so.

Comment: I typically use    {
            "_id": { "$gt": null }
        }, for all (no other filters since it uses the built in primary index.)    Else modify for the key(s) of your index. I think gt is faster than neq, but maybe not.